# Issue with forwarding copy constructor

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding

Anyone know why the forwarding copy ctor does not work?

Compiler error about one type being a vector and other a stack ???

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class stack{
public:
    stack();

    template<class X>
    stack(X&& other);

    template<typename X>
    void push(X&& element);

    T const & top() const;

    void pop();

    inline std::size_t const size() const;

    typedef std::vector<T> vector_type;

private:
    std::vector<T> elements;
};


template<class T>
stack<T>::stack(){}

template<class T>
template<class X>
stack<T>::stack(X&& other) : elements(std::forward<typename X>(other.elements)){

}

template<class T>
template<class X>
void stack<T>::push(X&& element){
    this->elements.push_back(std::forward<X>(element));
}

template<class T>
T const & stack<T>::top() const{
    return this->elements[this->elements.size() -1];
}

template<class T>
inline std::size_t const stack<T>::size() const{
    return this->elements.size();
}

template<class T>
void stack<T>::pop(){
    this->elements.pop_back();
}

template<class T,int N>
stack<T> get_stack_of_n_defaults(){

    stack<T> s;

    for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i){
        s.push( T()); // should pass by rvalue ref;
    }

    return s;

}


int main()
{

    stack<int> s = get_stack_of_n_defaults<int,5>();

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){
        s.push(i);
    }

    cout << s.size() << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i){
        cout << s.top() << endl;;
        s.pop();
    }

    cout << s.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what you mean when you say it dosn't work?

Comment: You probably don't want to use names like `stack` after `using namespace std;`. Also, post the compiler error itself. Finally, you can only have one list of template arguments. Combine `template<typename T> template<typename X>` into `template<typename T, typename X>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're referring to this line:

```
std::forward<typename X>(other.elements)
```

The type of `other.elements` is not `X`.

I believe this will work:

```
std::forward<X>(other).elements
```